# Converting jks keystore to p12 without password

Tags: android, pkcs#12, jks

I have a JKS .keystore with no password associated that I want to convert to a .p12 key, where that .p12 doesn't have a password either. When I use `keystore` Java util it will not continue without entering a password for the generated p12. What's the simplest way to get this .keystore key in .p12 form?

The keystore I am converting is Xamarin's: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/MD5_SHA1/

Answer (score -1):

Actually we can't generate .jks file without password. just check below,

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias jwtkey -keystore server.jks
```

as well as we can't convert .jks file .p12 format. just check below,

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore server.jks -destkeystore server.p12 -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcalias jwtkey -destalias jwtkey
```